# Sqlite multiple Updates

Tags: ubuntu, sqlite, lazarus

I have a Table that the User can bulk change a Column but only for some "like" records. For instance, **some** zipcodes.

```
zipcode = 12345  // Need to change this one
zipcode = 23456
zipcode = 12345  // Not this one
zipcode = 34567
zipcode = 12345  // Need to change this one
zipcode = 12345  // Need to change this one
zipcode = 12345  // Not not this one
```

Clearly I can't just use "WHERE zipcode = 12345"

Currently I am creating a StringList with the recID (an AutoInc) of each record that needs to be changed, then iterating though each one with

```
for i:=0 to slChange.Count-1 do
begin
  tStr:=' UPDATE Names SET Zipcode = '80000' WHERE recID = '+QuotedStr(slChange[i])+';';
  dm.sqlEmails.SQL.Text:=tStr;
  dm.sqlEmails.ExecSQL;
end;
```

If there are a lot of records to change it is taking quite some time.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you using a transaction?

Comment: Thanks for looking, yes but no idea how to use that to do this either. :)

Comment: Is this a "yes" or a "no"?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can speed up your code is using parameters. You prepare the query only once so the DBMS doesn't need to parse and plan execution of the query repetitively. Then you are sending only parameter values and calling [**ExecSQL**](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/sqldb/tcustomsqlquery.execsql.html). Another thing that can improve performance is using of the assigned [**Transaction**](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/sqldb/tsqlquery.transaction.html) object. Here is a code showing both mentioned things:

```
dm.sqlEmails.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE Names SET Zipcode = :ZipCode WHERE RecID = :RecID';

dm.sqlEmails.Transaction.StartTransaction;
try
  for i := 0 to slChange.Count-1 do
  begin
    dm.sqlEmails.Params.ParamByName('Zipcode').AsString := '80000';
    dm.sqlEmails.Params.ParamByName('RecID').AsString := slChange[i];
    dm.sqlEmails.ExecSQL;
  end;
  dm.sqlEmails.Transaction.Commit;
except
  dm.sqlEmails.Transaction.Rollback;
  raise;
end;
```